# Wrong characters with OdbcDataAdapter

Tags: c#, encoding, paradox

I use OdbcDataAdapter to get data from Paradox DB.

```
public static DataSet GetDataSetFromAdapter(DataSet dataSet, DataTable dataTable, string connectionString, string queryString)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            adapter.FillSchema(dataTable, SchemaType.Source);
            connection.Close();
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

I use FillSchema() method to get schema. But "." replaces to "#" in column name and a few symbols (e.g. "ä") replaces to another symbols too. How can I fix it?

Comment: whats in your connection string and querystring?

Comment: @JakeSteffen "Driver={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 7.X;DefaultDir=" + path + ";Dbq=" + path + ";CollatingSequence=ASCII;"

Comment: And the querystring?  Are you escaping column names in the query?

Comment: Query = "select * from HOUSE" (I have HOUSE.DB file with columns, but a few characters in column names are wrong - "#" instead of ".", "Д" instead of "a",... )